# Flickering HTML Form button radio Javascript true/false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

I would like to make a button which I can put on "true/false" on a certain time with javascript. I want to make a flickering button. How could I do this in Javascript?

I tried something like this:

```
    <td colspan="1" class="button" tabindex="1">
      <input type="radio" tabindex="-1">
    </td>
```

__

```
 setTimeout(function() {
    $("*[tabindex='1']").find('input').get(0).checked = true;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_radio
(This button)

Comment: Where is the rest of your `setTimeout` function

Answer (score 3):

This checks/unchecks the button randomly and you can certainly change the logic behind when the button should be on vs. off, but it shows how to check and uncheck the radio button natively (no JQuery) with the addition or removal of the `checked` attribute on the Radio Button.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("rad");
setInterval(function(){
  var rnd = Math.random();
  console.log(rnd);
  rnd > .5 ? btn.setAttribute("checked", "checked") : btn.removeAttribute("checked");
}, 500);
```

```html
<input id="rad" type="radio">
```

Comment: How can I set these at a certain time? I want to make a small animation with more of these "radio" buttons. Sorry If it is a stupid question, just new to coding (:

Comment: The 500 at the end of the code represents the interval between calls to the function that generates the random number. It is measured in milliseconds, so 500 means every half second.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, Last quick question, What If I want to have more on a page? [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Danisk2010/8sbt5oua/4/) For example when I want 02/05/03 to all flicker.

Comment: @danisk Then, you would need to duplicate what I've shown for each button

Comment: @ScottMarcus [link](https://jsfiddle.net/kbLu98g4/6/)

Comment: @Danisk You have to do the work on this. I've given you code. Now you just need to duplicate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work if you put the `<td>` element inside `<table>` tags.

If the `<td>` is outside of a table element, it is removed so you cannot access the radio button by searching for the parent `td`.

To make the button flicker, try having the function reset itself:

```
function buttonOnAfterDelay()
{   
   var $radioButton = $("*[tabindex='1']").find('input').get(0);
   if ($radioButton.checked)
        $radioButton.checked = false;
   else $radioButton.checked = true;
   setTimeout(function() {buttonOnAfterDelay()}, 1000);
}

buttonOnAfterDelay();
```

Comment: There should not be parenthesis after the function reference in setTimeout and that reference should be the only thing in the first parameter. Your syntax only makes sense when the function to be called needs a parameter passed to it. Also, you can remove the if then structure from your code and simply toggle the checked property of the radio button to !checked since that property stores a Boolean